# Hadoop map reduce java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

```
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), " *$&#/\t\n\f\"'\\,.:;?![](){}<>~-_");
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String term = itr.nextToken().toLowerCase();
            List<Pair<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> map = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>>>();
            /*here i am performing some operations*/
            for (Pair<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>> i : map){
                String w1 = i.getKey();
                Text word = new Text(w1);
                Pair<Integer, Integer> newValue = i.getValue();
                String merge = String.valueOf(newValue.getKey()) + " " + String.valueOf(newValue.getValue());
                Text val = new Text(merge);
                /*sending both the arguments as text into my context.*/
                context.write(word, val);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Reducer1 extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Text values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        /* here i want to extract the values, i tried using for loop but its saying cannot iterate, its expecting something iterable.*/
        for (Text t : values)
        {
            /*this is not working. I know we can use Iterable<IntWritable> for integers but in my case it is text.
        }
        //context.write(key, values);
    }
}
```

Please see the comment lines for better understanding of my problem.
Is there any way to **extract the Text values in the reducer**. `For` loop is expecting something `iterable`.

Comment: That isn't the correct signature for the `reduce(...)` method. Look at some WordCount tutorials.

Comment: Please show these "some operations" you're doing, otherwise that inner loop does nothing. Refer to [mcve] for more information (which means also show your expected inputs and outputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reducer, you would get an `Iterable<Text>`, which you must loop over and split on a space to recreate the String values for each `merge` string that the mapper wrote.

Note: Splitting on a space won't be very reliable if the `newValue.getKey()` in the map contains strings itself